# gala and plank take too much CPU with nvidia drivers

Tags: plank, gala

I have a high end dell precision T7610 workstation with Nvidia Graphics card. I tried installing both ubuntu and elementary OS on the system. With Ubuntu running top shows barely any CPU use on idle. With elementaryOS top should 20-40% cpu use distributed mainly across gala and plank processes and at time Xorg.

I tried updating to Nvidia 430 drivers, running nvidia configuration etc. The drivers are working fine and all tests are doing OK. There seems to be rendering issue with gala and plank that make them constantly use too much CPU.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hmm. On my PC (elementary 5, AMD, NVIDIA 430 driver) gala usually never takes up more than 3 % of processor power, while plank hardly ever goes above 0 %.